# Using dashes for showing a dichotomy spelling

Tags: typography

I have trouble with deciding how to use dashes in the following case:

> Before moving on, it is worth noting that the complex -- (non-complex)
>   simple dichotomy is not the same as the complicated --
>   (not-complicated) simple dichotomy.

In the text elsewhere I use en-dash (--) to signal an interjection, so technically, here it would seem that "(non-complex) simple dichotomy is not the same as the complicated" is an interjection, while it is really not.

If I did not have to make distinctions between non-complex and non-complicated simple, I would just put "complex--simple dichotomy", without the spaces, but adding the parts in parenthesis would make it look silly, and I am not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps use a / or a | instead of a — to mark the dichotomous contrasts?

Comment: the / sounds (looks) good

Comment: Or, you could swap the position of the parenthesised words : complex--simple (non-complex) ...